# USAJMO $2019$ problem $1$ Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> There are $a+b$ bowls arranged in a row, numbered $1$ through $a+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are given positive integers. Initially, each of the first $a$ bowls contains an apple, and each of the last $b$ bowls contains a pear.
> A legal move consists of moving an apple from bowl $i$ to bowl $i+1$ and a pear from bowl $j$ to bowl $j-1$, provided that the difference $i-j$ is even. We permit multiple fruits in the same bowl at the same time. The goal is to end up with the first $b$ bowls each containing a pear and the last $a$ bowls each containing an apple. Show that this is possible if and only if the product $ab$ is even.

Now in [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2019_USAJMO_Problems/Problem_1) solution(3) how $A_1-A_2$ is invariant ?

Comment: The invariant seems obvious to me. Can you show your attempts at understanding it and where you're stuck at?

Comment: You should read the solution by sa2001 in the aops thread once of this problem !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.)

**Hint:** Show that for each legal move, an apple goes from an odd to even bowl iff a pear goes from an odd to even bowl.

> $i,j$ have the same parity.
>   $i+1, j-1$ have the same parity.

Hence, $ A _ 1 - A_2$ is invariant.

> $A_1$ increases (resp decreases) by 1 iff $A_2$ increases (resp decreases) by 1.

---

FWIW Solution 2 and 3 are essentially the same. So if you understood solution 2, then you should understand solution 3.